# Can`t get JRebel to work

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, jrebel

I decided to try social JRebel for an open-source, personal project and I cannot get this working.
I use Eclipse Indigo IDE and I have downloaded JRebel via Eclipse marketplace and activated JRebel with my free license. I have setup the Glassfish application server with enable JRebel and disable auto publish.

Here is my **rebel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com   http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">

<classpath>
    <dir name="D:/workspace/jee/catiJava/src/ro/cati/actions"></dir>                   
</classpath>

<web>
    <link target="/">
        <dir name="D:/workspace/jee/catiJava/WebContent">
        </dir>
    </link>
</web>
```

and my project structure looks like this

[image: Project Structure]

The problem is that after I change something in `DashboardAction.java` which is under the package `ro.cati.actions` as a source nothing happens. I still have to redeploy in order to see the actual changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the source directory you should have the compile/build directory in <classpath> of your rebel.xml. So for example if the classes in src/ get compiled to bin/ you should have:

```
...
<classpath>
  <dir name="D:/workspace/jee/catiJava/bin/ro/cati/actions"></dir>                   
</classpath>
...
```

JRebel works with the compiled .class files and depends on the IDE to compile them.